# Running tessaract on iOS 7

Tags: xcode, ios7, text, xcode5, tesseract

I'm working on a project where i have to take an image and convert the textual context into sound.At first stage i have to convert those image into text(english).I'm using tessaract API's for converting that image into text(en).I have been trying to follow up tessaract 
tutorials for completing the steps.But it is my unfortunate that i haven't found any tutorils which give me the image to text conversion without any error.
Last time i got a template from online.But it is not working and also not showing any error.
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS
If anyone please check the link and please tell me why it is not running on iOS device or simulator.I have been using Xcode 5.1.I also want a better reference or suggestion regarding my problem.Thanks!